# Convert Network share path to a physical folder path

Tags: c#, directory, filesystemwatcher, audit, shared-directory

I have a console application that is using a FileSystemWatcher to watch a folder, which fires off an event when there is a file/folder deleted.

My Simplified Code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace FileWatcherConsole
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
            {
                Path = "\\Server1",
                IncludeSubdirectories = true,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
                Filter = "*.*"
            };
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(program.OnDeleted);
            new AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
        }

        private void OnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

The application works as expected, except for when watching a network shared folder where the output is

```
\\Server1\SharedFolder
```

However I would instead like the physical path of the folder:

```
C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\SharedFolder
```

So is there a way to programmatically convert the network path to a physical path ?

I know one solution is to use the physical path when instantiating FileSystemWatcher, however this is not ideal as physical location of the network share folder can change.

P.S. If you deem necessary the reasoning behind this, I need the physical path as I am comparing the the event path [e.FullPath] with system auditing events

Comment: [This](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/get-local-path-from-unc-path/) seems like it might be what you need?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: Hi @NetMage, can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ManagementObjectSearcher` in the `System.Management` namespace you can query the remote server for the `Win32_Share` definition of the share in WMI and build the corresponding local path.

The article [Get local path from UNC path](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/get-local-path-from-unc-path/) has sample code detailing how to do this.